# Search result for deployment returns nothing on Kubctl while on helm it works

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I have created an autoscale deployment,
while searching for the deployment on helm `helm ls --all gw-autoscale-t1`, leads to a result of:

`gw-autoscale-t1 1               Sat Dec 21 03:32:12 2019        DEPLOYED        gatewayservice-0.1.0    1.0             dev`

While searching for the deployment by Kubectl: `kubectl get deploy -n dev | findstr gw-autoscale-t1` returns nothing.

**Why is that happening?**

Comment: In what OS are you trying to use that command? I'm guessing Windows. Please elaborate.

Comment: if you do kubectl get all -A do you then see it along with everything else?

Comment: I'm using windows 10 and Apparently `kubectl get all -A` found the lost deployment. Not sure why is that?      The result of the deployment is: `dev         horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/gw-autoscale-t1   Deployment/gw-autoscale-t1   <unknown>/80%   1         3         0          13h`.       But I can't see its pods (although I can see the service/gw-autoscale-t1)

Comment: Could you please post the output of theses commands:`kubectl get deployments gw-autoscale-t1 -n dev` and `kubectl describe deployment gw-autoscale-t1 -n dev`. Please verify if you are running the commands in the correct namespace.